# Call Rest APIs parallely and combina their results - Java + Quarkus

Tags: java, concurrency, reactive-programming, quarkus

I need to call multiple APIs in parallel and combine their results as array and return to the consumer.

Here is some context:

- I would get the list of "providers" in the request. This list can have at least 1 or at most 10 values. This list could be different in different requests.
- For each item in the list, I need to call a REST API. For example, if list contains [A,B], then I will be calling RestApiA and RestApiB, combine the result of both these APIs and return to the consumer.
- These API calls will be independent of each other and should be called parallely.
- If any of the API call fails, we should log an error but the rest of the API calls should still succeed.

I came across this article https://quarkus.io/blog/mutiny-concurrent-uni/ but the problem here is I need to hardcode the functions I need to call concurrently.

In my case, I would know at runtime what all methods I need to call.

Comment: I don't understand the `I would know at runtime what all methods I need to call` part. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Based on the list of providers I would be getting in request, I would know what all APIs I need to call at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I’m typing this from my phone and out of my head, so apologies for errors but you should do something like this:

```
Uni<Tuple> parallelCalls(List params) {
   return Uni.combine()
             .all()
             .unis(
                restCallA(params),    
                restCallB(params))
             .asTuple();
}


Uni<ResultA> restCallA(List params) {
      return Multi.createFrom().iterable(params)
                  .invoke(param-> clientA.send(param))
                  //combine results & return as uni
}
```